# GAS: Calling functions defined in an add-on from bound script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written google app script code for a spreadsheet. I want to publish part of it as an add-on,
the other part (which stays as script bound to the spreadsheet) should be able to call functions in that add-on.
I didn't find any hint in the google documentation about this.
I read how calling functions in a library. Is calling functions in an add-on similar?
Reason behind is I want to hide the logic of the add-on code, but give users the freedom to change the non add-on code.

Comment: [Why “is this possible?” is a poor question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to call functions from inside an Add-On.

However, the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#creating_a_library) for Libraries mentions how to make methods and properties private, under the Best practices section, number 3.

You can use these methods to create a structure similar to `private` encapsulation on languages like Java and others, where you have private methods and properties and then public methods that allow users to manipulate those.

## What about debugging?

If you debug a project with libraries, you will be able to browse the code on the libraries as read-only.

While that is an expected result, since other languages also have it (if you are debugging a java code, even if there is no source provided, you can still see the JVM method headers and the stack-trace.), there is not much to be done.

However, you can use a clever method to obfuscate your code:

Consider publishing a web app that receives the data you plan on manipulating and interact with that instead with Apps Script's `UrlFetchApp`.

You can also make a library to "hide" the fact that you are calling an web app from your non-debugging users (after all, they would be able to see your code). But your "hidden" code would be safe.

Comment: But under "Testing and debugging your library" section is written:

When you are using a debugger within a project that has a library included you are able to step into a function of the included library. The code shows up in the debugger in the read-only mode and at the right version.

That means I can not hide the code.

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for that. I suggest you use a Web App to do your processing\