# SF Connector with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, salesforce

I have connected my gsheet to SF using the Data connector for Salesforce and have imported a report.
Is there a way to refresh this report using Apps Script? Or even import another report?

Comment: `Data connector for Salesforce` seems to be an add-on. Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693085/14779804 answer your question?

Comment: Hmm yes I guess it does thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GAS: Calling functions defined in an add-on from bound script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58682542/gas-calling-functions-defined-in-an-add-on-from-bound-script)

Answer (score 0):

The Data connector for Salesforce has an option to automatically refresh the data in your sheets (see image below). I think this answers what you're looking for.

[Salesforce data connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9whH.png)

If you want to build sales tools in a spreadsheet (find leads, automate reporting, etc) you might want to check `rows.com` . We combine a spreadsheet editor with built-in integrations and automation (Salesforce, Linkedin, Crunchbase, ...), all using formulas, without code.

Here's our integration with Salesforce
https://rows.com/integrations/salesforce