# Call salesforce connector google sheets plugin from Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, salesforce

I am trying to automate inserting data into Salesforce from Google Sheets on a regular schedule. I would like to do this by:

1. Writing an Apps Script function that uses the Salesforce Connector to push data from a table in google sheets into Salesforce. I would like to configure the mapping of my table to my Salesforce data within this function.
2. Then I would like to schedule this function to run with a trigger.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried to create an apps script and add the Salesforce Connector (https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/salesforce_connector/857627895310) as a library to reference but I could not find the Script ID. The number in the above URL does not appear to be the Script ID. My thinking is that if I can add the script as a library, I can inspect its code.

I then tried to play around in the editor and realized that I can call the ImportDatatoSalesforce object[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXEb.png) but there isn't any useful documentation around it.

Because of this, I'm stuck on knowing how to use this object to call its native functionality to do what I want to do.

Comment: Related questions: [SF Connector with Apps Script [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65700304/1330560), [GAS: Calling functions defined in an add-on from bound script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58682542/1330560)